# dynamically create a database and table in it with laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I want to create a new database dynamically and database(user) with privileges, tables in the new database for every new user on the fly and only with the code without using command prompt/console. and yes I am almost new to laravel but I have good knowledge of PHP.

I did some search on `DB::statement` for creating a database but did not get much. I also tried something like `artisan::call(migrate)` for migration but in that too did not get anything very clear.

I would like solutions with laravel code rather than commands from/for command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Eloquent capsule manager to create a table in the code.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;



        $capsule = new Capsule();

        $capsule->addConnection([
            'driver' => config('database.connections.mysql.driver),
            'host' => config('database.connections.mysql.host),
            'database' => config('database.connections.mysql.database),
            'username' => config('database.connections.mysql.username),
            'password' => config('database.connections.mysql.password),
            'charset' => config('database.connections.mysql.charset),
            'collation' => config('database.connections.mysql.collation),
            'prefix' => config('database.connections.mysql.prefix),
        ]);
```

And then you can create table like so. be sure to check the table is exists or not:

```
         if(!Capsule::schema()->hasTable($this->table)){

            Capsule::schema()->create($this->table, function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
                $table->charset = 'utf8';
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('email')->unique();
               .
               .
               .
                });
            }
```

Comment: I am new so please provide some easy way. I am not getting it very clearly this one. and in a very simple way can you just provide me the code create a database in laravel just with code no commands from the command prompt

Comment: This is the easiest explanation. are you familiar with OOP? @vipulv1201

Comment: @vipulv1201 also are you familiar with migrations or not?

Comment: yup, I am aware of migration and also the oop concept.

Comment: and I got this for creating a table in the database but can you please provide me a code to create a database from the code dynamically using may be DB::statement or any other way.!!

Comment: @franc whats the problem?